# Floating bar is hiding, need to place

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float, wordpress-theming

Wordpress. Theme 1Page = Masonry WordPress News.
Plugin - Digg Digg floating social icons.
address: http://blog.standout.guru/ enabled only for posts.
In the source I see that it is on the page - it starts with:

`<div class='dd_outer'><div class='dd_inner'><div id='dd_ajax_float'><div class='dd_button_v'>`

Something is hiding it I suppose. I tried other floating bars but the same result.
Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Just try out adding a position:fixed , border: 2px solid red , z-index:999999 properties to it. It will just help to notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the z-index? Like so:

`<div class='dd_outer' style='z-index: 9999;'><div class='dd_inner'><div id='dd_ajax_float'><div class='dd_button_v'>`

Comment: I couldn't see the website, I'm sorry. But I noticed that div ".dd_ajax_float" has a property `left: -120px`. Changing that to `left: 0px` fixed it.